# How did Ant-Man get trapped?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In *Ant-Man*, right at the end of the main heist;

> Darren Cross successfully traps Ant-Man by baiting him into the place where the minature Yellowjacket suit is contained. This implies that Darren Cross not only knew that the heist was going to take place, but that he also knew exactly how it was going to be performed.

How did this character know the plan, and when in the movie did he figure it out?

Comment: I thought they were going to reveal that he placed a listening device on the photo of Hope, given how the camera focuses on him picking it up, then cuts away.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's strongly implied that Cross actually did learn everything he needed from

> reading the plans on the table in Pym's house.

Hank and company *think* they've avoided a major issue when Cross seems oblivious to their plans. They assume that Scott and the ants managed to hide the evidence. However, we later find out that

> Cross saw Hope in the house

which means he almost certainly saw everything else he needed to see at the same time.

Comment: Also, immediately after he left the house, he intentionally told Hope about the new security procedures over the phone. The infiltration plans were altered based on that information, so Cross could've guessed the details of their new plans based on the information he leaked himself.

Answer (score 1):

This character had suspicion that Hank Pym has the shrink suit technology and took extra precautions to keep the building secure (he mentions extra dense grid on every opening) from ant-sized infiltrators.

Only things of value that were in the building were the yellowjacket suit and the shrink technology. 
The only way to steal / destroy the suit would be if Ant Man crawled inside. He might have considered this probability and took some precautions. The timing was purely coincidental. He also invited Hank just to torment him.